# -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Here,

**NSString *decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];**

"decryptedStr" is getting "decryptedData" has been working fine in simulator.
but

**it has not been working fine in iPhone devices.** i got an error message is 
**-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil**'.
plz help me.

this is my code

```
NSString *stringIndex1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrAthigaaramList1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dictDecryptList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<[arrD_Chapter count];i++)//50 Chapter wise
    {
        stringIndex1 = [arrD_Chapter objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData  *b64DecData = [Base64 decode:stringIndex1];
        NSData *decryptedData = [[NSData alloc]init];
        decryptedData= [b64DecData AESDecryptWithPassphrase:@"mypassword"];
        NSString *decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];

        if (decryptedStr) {
            NSLog(@"Decryped Data Base 64 encoded = %@",decryptedStr);
            [arrAthigaaramList1 addObject:decryptedStr];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR decrypting!!!");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please don't repost your questions; edit the originals
 instead.

Answer (score 1):

change these lines:

```
    NSData *decryptedData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    decryptedData= [b64DecData AESDecryptWithPassphrase:@"mypassword"];
    NSString *decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
```

to this:

```
    NSData *decryptedData= [b64DecData AESDecryptWithPassphrase:@"mypassword"];
    if([decryptedData length] > 0)
    {
        NSString *decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData  
                                                       encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
    } else {
       NSLog(@"Hmmm, why is decrypted data a zero byte object??");
    }
```